# Accesing array of structs gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm implementing a hashing algorithm with a key/value pair datatype. I store the dictionary as an array of data entries. I `malloc` it but when I iterate through the elements that i have just allocated on the `inicializar_cerrada` function, program segfaults at 2nd iteration.

My partners and i have been trying to figure this one out but the problem has stuck.

SSCCE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// ...

#define TAM 11

typedef struct entrada_ {
    int ocupada;
    char clave [LONGITUD_CLAVE];
    char sinonimos [LONGITUD_SINONIMOS];
} entrada;

typedef entrada *tabla_cerrada;

void inicializar_cerrada(tabla_cerrada *diccionario, int tam) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        diccionario[i]->ocupada = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    tabla_cerrada d = malloc(TAM * sizeof(entrada));    
    inicializar_cerrada(&d, TAM);   
}
```

Comment: In the `main` function you create an "array" of *structure objects*, not an array of pointers to structures (which the function `inicializar_cerrada` treats it like).

Comment: Do not confuse yourself by typedef'ing pointer-types.

Comment: Where is the `mostrar_cerrada` function? Does your compiler give some warning? `diccionario[i]->ocupada` This looks fishy. `diccionario` is the address of a pointer `d`, not an array.

Comment: If you know that is segfaults at second iteration, you seem to run it in a debugger. Did you check all the variables? Especially where the pointers point to?

Comment: You might try `diccionario[i]->ocupada` => `(*diccionario)[i].ocupada`

Comment: Why `tabla_cerrada *diccionario` and not `tabla_cerrada diccionario`? Because you confused yourself? ;-)

Comment: @Gerhardh, you mean `(*diccionario)[i].ocupada`.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Yes I just saw it. ;) Thanks

Comment: It would be simpler to have the function take `d`, not `&d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Gerhardh commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181935/c-accesing-array-of-structs-gives-segmentation-fault/54182149#comment95192279_54181935):

> You might try diccionario[i]->ocupada => (*diccionario)[i].ocupada

It worked great!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LONGITUD_CLAVE 30
#define LONGITUD_SINONIMOS 300
#define TAM 11

typedef struct entrada_ {
    int ocupada;
    char clave [LONGITUD_CLAVE];
    char sinonimos [LONGITUD_SINONIMOS];
} entrada;

typedef entrada *tabla_cerrada;

void inicializar_cerrada(tabla_cerrada *diccionario, int tam) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        (*diccionario)[i].ocupada = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    tabla_cerrada d = malloc(TAM * sizeof(entrada));    
    inicializar_cerrada(&d, TAM);   
}
```

Comment: As long as `void inicializar_cerrada(tabla_cerrada *diccionario, int tam)` is not explicitly required to look like this you solution is combating causes and symptoms although correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the asterisk from the function definition for `diccionario` argument. `tabla_cerrada` is a pointer already:

   `void inicializar_cerrada(tabla_cerrada diccionario, int tam) {`
2. Change the arrow notation to dot notation. `diccionario[i]` is a `struct`, not a pointer to one:

   `diccionario[i].ocupada = 0;`
3. Drop the `&` from the function call, `d` is of type `tabla_cerrada`, which is a pointer:

   `inicializar_cerrada(d, TAM);`

Answer (score 0):

Drop this

```
typedef entrada *tabla_cerrada;
```

and just do

```
void inicializar_cerrada(entrada *diccionario, int tam) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        diccionario[i].ocupada = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    entrada * d = malloc(TAM * sizeof(entrada));    
    inicializar_cerrada(d, TAM);    
}
```

or even saver:

```
void inicializar_cerrada(entrada *diccionario, size_t tam) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tam; ++i) {
        printf("%zu\n", i);
        diccionario[i].ocupada = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    entrada * d = malloc(TAM * sizeof *d);  
    inicializar_cerrada(d, TAM);    
}
```

If you are forced to use

```
typedef entrada *tabla_cerrada;
```

do

```
void inicializar_cerrada(tabla_cerrada diccionario, size_t tam) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tam; ++i) {
        printf("%zu\n", i);
        diccionario[i].ocupada = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    tabla_cerrada d = malloc(TAM * sizeof *d);  
    inicializar_cerrada(d, TAM);    
}
```

Still `tabla_cerrada` is not a "table" (aka array) but a pointer. As I said do not confuse yourself.

Comment: I cannot drop that line, its part of the project specs.

Comment: @Tretorn: Updated my answer.

Comment: @alk You're welcome sir, we're the extra pair of eyes that you need to nitpick. :)